# Datepicker For Bootstrap : update value

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am currently using [Datepicker for Bootsrap](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) and am trying to dynamically change its value after attaching it.

I have initialized it this way :

```
$("#VH_chooseWeek").datepicker({
        weekStart : 1
    })
    .on('changeDate', function(ev){
        VH_displayWeek(ev.date);
        $("#VH_chooseWeek").datepicker('hide');
        VH_main();
    });
```

And trying to update it this way :

```
var VH_tamperWeek = function(nbWeek){
    currentToday.setDate(currentToday.getDate() + 7*nbWeek);
    $("VH_chooseWeek").datepicker('setValue', currentToday);
}
```

No exception is raised but it seems the 'setValue' method isn't working. Do you have some kind of idea to fix the problem or a workaround that could do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I made it working was by using an another plugin called DateTimePicker;

You can find it [there](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.php);